# How to share iPhone application with different users on the Mac?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator

I want to know can we share the iPhone application in Simulator with the different users in the Mac system, without sharing the source code of that iPhone application with other users?
If yes how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know (without jailbreaking) to share your application is by doing the following:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html